# Read last line of the log file from remote server in python

Tags: python

I am trying to read a last line of the .log file from the remote server, But getting "No such file or directory:". I am not sure how to open the connection with server.

```
from fabric.connection import Connection
HostName='\\\\Server\xyz.log'

with open(HostName,'r') as f:

    for line in f:

        pass
    last_line = line
print(last_line)
```

Comment: Shouldn't `HostName='\\\\Server\xyz.log'` look like  `HostName='\\\\Server\\xyz.log'`? (Note the `\\x`)

Comment: I have tried the same but does not work. I have put the hostname as "\\Server\xyz.log" as well, but failed.

Comment: Try the various strings, but with the raw prefix: `r"\\Server\xyz.log"` for example. That should prevent any escapes with the backslash.

Comment: How do you normally access the remote server?

Comment: You are escaping the x with `\x` you should be using `\\x`.

Comment: Still the same error. We normally access the server via Remote Desktop Connection.

Comment: Your code currently just tries to open a file on the local system. If the connection is not available by default, then yes, that will fail. You should read up on how to best connect via RDC in Python.